# Why is the foreground on my ImageView not centered correctly on the background?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I am currently in the process of creating a music app and have run into a problem with drawing a music stave in the activities. This is what the activities look like without the staves:

[image]

Here is the code for one of the activites:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
tools:context="aphitech.musicappproject.MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:clickable="false">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/LowAb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rectangle"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/LowA"
            android:foreground="@drawable/stavelines"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="top" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spacer1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/RegAb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spacer2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/RegA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spacer3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/HighAb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spacer4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/HighA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>



    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I made a drawable of a music stave that I am trying to put on top of each image view because I am wanting to dynamically draw each note on top of that. Here is a picture of that:

[image]

Here is the code for that as well:

```
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
        <size android:height="20dp" />
        <padding android:bottom="20dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
        <size android:height="20dp" />
        <padding android:bottom="20dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
        <size android:height="20dp" />
        <padding android:bottom="20dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
        <size android:height="20dp" />
        <padding android:bottom="20dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
        <size android:height="20dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

And here is the what everything looks like together:

[image]

I am wanting to get the stave to be directly in the center of each rectangle but it is always too high or too low depending on the padding that I place on it. I am assuming that the problem is with the creation of the stave itself.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go with a table layout, set the root layout background to black, do a table layout and then add rows with a margin and background of white.  Use weight sum so all rows are set equal, and resizes to screen.  And considering you are going to be adding notes on dynamically, I would bring in each line as a seperate element, so you can call each line ID.  I added the code of what i just quickly drew up.

**TABLE LAYOUT**

```
<TableLayout
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

**ROW EXAMPLE**

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightCream"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:weightSum="5">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blackline"
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/line" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blackline"
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/line" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/blackline"
            android:contentDescription="@string/line"
            android:id="@+id/line3" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/line"
            android:background="@drawable/blackline"
            android:id="@+id/line4" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/line"
            android:background="@drawable/blackline"
            android:id="@+id/line5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

> > > > screen shot   [music.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg7t9.png)

I drew each line in paint with a top and bottom padding, and the back ground matching that of the row (white) . there was no padding to the left or right 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9ZoK.png)

doing a weightsum will split the rows sizes equally, linear layout with an vertical oritation allows you do apply the weight sum for each line so they are also split equally and should adapt on changes in screen size.

But i would highly recommend programming your layout programmatically rather then xml, due to the singular lines, applying java programming techniques will make it more flexible to work with and will give you cleaner code.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: No problem, having it set like a table will allow you to place the notes  across each row by applying columns ..(note per column).  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html